# How to change icon while also doing a changeTheme with onClick in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have succeded in creating a icon click to change the colorscheme of my website (line 21 and `changeTheme`), but when I click the icon I would also like it to change from `FaRegMoon` to `FaRegSun` and vice versa (i.e when I click it once it should change to `FaRegSun` and when I click it another time it should change to `FaRegMoon`

current code:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { FaRegMoon, FaRegSun } from "react-icons/fa"
import "./index.sass"

const changeTheme = () => {
    const item = localStorage.getItem("theme")
    let theme;
    if (item === "light") {
        theme = "";
        localStorage.setItem('theme', "")
    } else {
        theme = "light"
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light')
    }
    localStorage.setItem('theme', theme)
    document.body.className = localStorage.getItem("theme");
}

const ThemeToggle = () => {
    return (
        <div className='theme-toggle-button'>
            <FaRegMoon size={20} onClick={() => changeTheme() }/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ThemeToggle;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) Add a state for your icon inside ThemeToggle function

```html
const [icon, setIcon] = useState('FaRegMoon')
```

2.) Add a parameter to your changeTheme function.

```html
const changeTheme = (iconName) => { ... }
```

3.) Add the name of the icon argument you want to change to upon clicking

```html
<FaRegMoon size={20} onClick={() => changeTheme('FaRegSun') }/>
```

4.) Refactor your **ThemeToggle** code
(I used a ternary operator in returning a value for icon)

```html
const ThemeToggle = () => {
    const [icon, setIcon] = useState('FaRegMoon')

    //place your changeTheme function here with the added code

    const themeIsLight = (icon === 'FaRegSun');
    const Icon = themeIsLight ? <FaRegSun size={20} onClick={() => changeTheme('FaRegMoon') }/>
                              : <FaRegMoon size={20} onClick={() => changeTheme('FaRegSun') }/>
    return (
        <div className='theme-toggle-button'>
            {Icon}
        </div>
    )
}
```

5.) lastly, refactor your changeTheme function. The component would re-render depending on the theme that is passed on to the setState function. add this line of code on the last line of changeTheme function. Hoped this helped brother.

```html
setIcon(iconName)
```